# Can not convert HttpPostedFileBase object into byte array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, image-uploading

I am trying to create a method where I can pass an image file and retrieve bytes of that image file, so later I can store the bytes in database. Here is my code for the method.

```
private byte[] GetImageBytes(HttpPostedFileBase ProfilePhoto)
{
    if (ProfilePhoto != null)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            ProfilePhoto.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
            byte[] array = ms.GetBuffer();
            return array;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I get an array of bytes array[0], so there is nothing converted into bytes. In debug mode I can see that the ProfilePhoto is not null and it has Length property etc... I tried another way by replacing the code inside the method with the code below:

```
byte[] image = new byte[ProfilePhoto.ContentLength];
ProfilePhoto.InputStream
    .Read(image, 0, Convert.ToInt32(ProfilePhoto.ContentLength));
return image;
```

but again no success. It returns an array 0x0000... which is the default value.
Any idea how to solve this problem ? Probably it is very simple but I do not have knowledge on how to upload files in MVC

---

. I tried to find other ways to do that but none of them worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to seek to the start of the stream first, before copying it:

```
ProfilePhoto.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
ProfilePhoto.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
```

Comment: Thanks man, it solved my problem. In equivalence I found the problem in second way. I had to do `ProfilePhoto.InputStream.Position = 0;` and then everything worked fine :) cheers.