# Email sending with attachment issue

Tags: c#, email, model-view-controller, attachment

I am trying to send an email message to different users (with an attachment). The email is being sent, but only one user receives the attachment (image file). Other recipients receive something like empty picture, or picture with name and zero bytes.

I don't really understand what is going wrong. Here is code that I used for sending emails:

```
public void SendWithFile(string recipientName, string body, string subject = null, HttpPostedFileBase emailFile = null)
{
    using (var msg = new MailMessage())
    {
        msg.To.Add(recipientName);
        msg.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailServerSenderAdress"]);
        msg.Subject = subject;
        msg.Body = body;
        msg.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        msg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        msg.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;

        using (Attachment data = new Attachment(emailFile.InputStream, Path.GetFileName(emailFile.FileName), emailFile.ContentType))
        {
            msg.Attachments.Add(data);

            using (var client = new SmtpClient())
            {
                //client configs
                try
                {
                    client.Send(msg);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is where I call the send email method:

```
foreach (var recipent in notesRecipients)
{
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userEmail))
   {
       if (emailFile != null)
          emailService.SendWithFile(userEmail, message, null, emailFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are almost certainly reading the stream to the end on the first recipient and then subsequent reads are getting 0 bytes. You either need to seek the stream back to the beginning after calling Send or buffer the data.

Comment: Yes, you are right, on the next stage of foreach cycle HttpPostedFileBase has ContentLength of 0. How can i seek the stream? Thx

Comment: If the stream supports seeking, then you can set the Position to 0. If it does not support seeking you will have to read it into an auxiliary  stream and use that.

Comment: Refer to this one here @ФилиппВолошин https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37975559/can-not-convert-httppostedfilebase-object-into-byte-array

Comment: Is the message always identical? you can bcc everyone at once.

Answer (score 0):

You have to seek the stream from the beginning like below before you send the attachment:

```
emailFile.InputStream.Position = 0;
```

For more info you can refer to this question here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37975559/can-not-convert-httppostedfilebase-object-into-byte-array)